# Trying to update the file with the updated value with the below code but it is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tomcat, web-applications

from the above code, I am able to read the content of the file but not able to update the file.Basically, I am trying to update the file with every hit of the web application, trying to store the counter (hits to the website)

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var allText;
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.overrideMimeType('text/plain');
        rawFile.open("GET", "http://xyz.abc.com:8080/build-pipeline-custom-theme/count.txt", true);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if (rawFile.readyState === 4)
            {
                if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status === 0)
                {
                    allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    console.log(allText);
                    allText = allText + 1;
                    console.log(allText);
                }
            }
        }
        rawFile.open("POST", "http://xyz.abc.com:8080/build-pipeline-custom-theme/count.txt", true);
        rawFile.send("Abhay");


    });
```

Comment: `Basically, I am trying to update the file with every hit of the web application` Regardless of the issue with updating the file you'll most likely have concurrency issues using a file-based data store. There's lots of free third-party tools which are far more suited to this task and provide much more useful information, such as Google Analytics.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please give more details on third-party tools

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for pointing the above issue :)

Comment: All the info you need: https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/

Comment: also it will good if for now We will ignore the concurrency issue , then how i can update the file with the above code , what i am missing there